# MS Access VBA form date picker written in Access 2003 inoperable in Access 2016 please advise how to convert or make this work in Access 2016

Tags: date, ms-access, vba

I am on Windows 10 and running 32 bit Office 2016.

When I try to execute this piece of code:

```
Private Sub Form_Load() 
    If DatePart("ww", Format("01/" & Month(Date) & "/" & Year(Date), "dd/mm/yyyy", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek), vbThursday) = DatePart("ww", Date, vbThursday) Then
        FromDate.Value = Format("01/" & Month(Date) - 1 & "/" & Year(Date), "dd/mm/yyyy")
        ToDate.Value = DateAdd("d", -1, Format("01/" & Month(Date) & "/" & Year(Date), "dd/mm/yyyy"))
    Else
        FromDate.Value = Format("01/" & Month(Date) & "/" & Year(Date), "dd/mm/yyyy")
        ToDate.Value = DateAdd("d", -1, Format("01/" & Month(Date) + 1 & "/" & Year(Date), "dd/mm/yyyy"))
    End If
    If CountRows("rpt_all_hours") > 0 Then
        cmdClearTable.Enabled = True
        ViewTable.Enabled = True
    Else
        cmdClearTable.Enabled = False
        ViewTable.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

I get an error:

> Run Time Error 2683 there is no object in this control

The code stops at this line:

```
FromDate.Value = Format("01/" & Month(Date) - 1 & "/" & Year(Date),"dd/mm/yyyy")
```

I also got an Active X error when importing the form into an Access 2016 database from an `.mdb` file:

> There was an error loading an ActiveX control on one of your forms or reports.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Oh my - that code needs a thorough clean-up. *Never* use string handling for date manipulations, no exceptions.

As for the date picker - it is built-in in newer Access versions. Just set a date format for the textbox, and a small button is shown at the right which opens the date picker.

Then trash the old ActiveX control.